# What does Class.this mean?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I do understand that Class.this used in case of nested classes but I came across a code which is using it without any nested classes.

```
// Find the View that shows the numbers category
TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

// Set a click listener on that View
numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
       startActivity(numbersIntent);
   }
});
```

In the line:

```
 Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
```

Why is **MainActivity.this** used and why can't we use **this**.

Comment: if you use `this` there then you are referring to anonymous class not `MainActivity`

Comment: `new View.OnClickListener() {}` is a nested class.

Comment: Ohk Understood Thank you @shmosel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because here **new View.OnClickListener()** is anonymous inner class.